# Windows application to replace icon within another application

Tags: gratis, windows-7, user-interface, icon

I want to replace the default icon in an executable.  I'm looking for [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) software to do this that is compatible with [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7).

I strongly prefer [portable](/questions/tagged/portable) software, but this is not a requirement.

I have already created the new icon, and have it saved in a `.ico` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend IcoFX which by the way I am currently using.

Goods news is that it is **portable**, and can be downloaded as a .paf file.

> [IcoFX](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/icofx_portable) is an award winning freeware icon editor. It is an
>   all-in-one solution for icon creation, extraction and editing. It is
>   designed to work with Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 and
>   Macintosh icons supporting transparency.

**Other features**

- **Add, change or delete icons inside exe files**
- Support for Vista/7 icon with PNG compression
- Create icons for Windows 98 / ME / 2000 / XP / Vista / 7
- Create icon libraries
- Easily convert images to icons
- Support for transparency (alpha channel)

**Basic usage, to change the icon of an executable**;

- open the icoFX program and go to the **Tools** tab and click Resource Editor
- In the windows that comes, select open and navigate to the path of your executable
- After selecting the executable, right click on the program's current icon and choose **Change**

[image]

- Then choose your preferred .ico.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thats great! Anytime :)

Comment: Thank you again.  Really a great app.  BTW, don't forget to upvote questions you think are valuable! :)